# I have a error in GAPI: Failed to authenticate user

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have problem in Google Analytics API php:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GAPI: Failed to authenticate user. 
Error: ""' in /home/content/30/10731230/html/google_analytics/ga/gapi.class.php:418 
Stack trace: #0 /home/content/30/10731230/html/google_analytics/ga/gapi.class.php(62): gapi->authenticateUser('user', 'pass') 
             #1 /home/content/30/10731230/html/google_analytics/index.php(13): gapi->__construct('user', 'pass') 
             #2 {main} thrown in /home/content/30/10731230/html/google_analytics/ga/gapi.class.php on line 418
```

Comment: Stating the obvious, but have you confirmed your credentials you're using to authenticate?

Comment: @rog i don't know how to.. pls help me?